# CARGAR IMAGENES AL CLOUDINARY CON NESTJS

Tags: nestjs

ESTOY TRATANDO DE SUBIR IMAGENES AL CLOUDINARY PERO NO ME PERMITE
[![ESTOY TRATANDO DE SUBIR IMAGENES AL CLOUDINARY PERO NO ME PERMITE][1]][1]

```
@Controller('images')
```

export class ImagesController {
constructor(private readonly imagesService: ImagesService){}

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
   storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './upload',
        filename: renameImage
    }),

    
    
    cloudinary: v2.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLD_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLD_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLD_API_SECRET,
    
    
    })
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no te permite? ¿cuál es el error?, ¿Puedes poner el código en formato de código por favor?, te aconsejo leerte [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hola, ya acabo de poner el codigo